# How to access inherited attributes of a property in a partial class?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have the following classes:

```
interface IEntityWithId
{
    int id { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntityMetaData
{
    [Display(Name="Name of my property")]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyEntity : MyEntityMetaData, IEntityWithId
{
}

/* Autogenerated code somewhere else */
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a `IQueryable<IEntityWithId>` in which the objects are actually of type `MyEntity`.

I used this code to extract display names:

```
private static List<string> GetColumnNames<T>(IQueryable<T> query) where T : class
{
    Type elementType = query.ElementType;
    var defaultColumns = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    var columnNames =
    (
        from
            p in elementType.GetProperties()
        where
           IsBindableType(p.PropertyType) &&
           (p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)

        select
        new
        {
            DisplayName = (DisplayNameAttribute)p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault(),
            Display = (DisplayAttribute)p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault(),
            Name = p.Name
        }
    ).Select
    (
        name =>
        name.DisplayName != null ?
        name.DisplayName.DisplayName :
        name.Display != null ?
        name.Display.Name :
        name.Name
    ).ToList();
    return columnNames;
}
```

But it doesn't actually work (display names are null). I do get correct type and properties within the method, but the attributes are missing. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that those are attributes of a parent class and/or my class being a partial one.

Is there something I can do to actually get those attributes inside my method (I can't really change my input type)?

**Edit:** Having run into the problem yet again, I believe that the answer to this question is in the part of MVC code responsible for bringing `ViewData.ModelMetadata` to life (because `ViewData.ModelMetadata` has correct those display names, even when they are as oddly inherited as in this question). This [post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/why-you-dont-need-modelmetadataattributes.html) makes me believe that this part of MVC that I'm looking for is a `ModelMetadataProvider`. One of those days I'll have to analyze the code...

Comment: As far as MVC goes, those attributes are recognized. I'm guessing my solution is not that different from using `[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetaData))]`, since the result is the same (MVC recognizes those, but `GetProperties()` doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

The autogenerated code is hiding `MyEntityData.MyProp` with `MyEntity.Prop`. `MyEntity.Prop` is to all efects a completely new method and does not inherit any attributes that might be defined in `MyEntityData.MyProp`.

If possible, you should refactor `MyEntityData` to:

```
public class MyEntityMetaData
{
    [Display(Name="Name of my property")]
    public virtual string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

And make the code generation tool override said method:

```
/* Autogenerated code somewhere else */
public partial class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the autogenerated code. MVC does respect those attributes, but maybe regular C# doesn't. I also tried using `[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetaData))]`, but the result was the same. My best guess is that I need to rewrite my method to somehow use `ModelMetadata` or dig out how `ModelMetadata` does its magic (it's in ASP.NET MVC code).